# Convert XML to CSV or XLSX

Tags: ms-office, file-conversion, xml

I have a large XML file (11MB) which I need to open in Excel for processing. I have MS Excel for Mac 2011 and when I try to open the XML file, it just opens it as plain text (seems that this is a feature not supported by Excel for Mac 2011).

I was expecting to see the XML item data split to rows and columns, just like Excel for windows does.

Is there another way to convert it? I have looked at online converters, but haven't found one that can process large files...

Comment: XML **is** plain text. What did you expect to see?

Comment: @Tetsujin Excel for Windows knows how to parse some formats of XML files into a table

Comment: Have you tried OpenOffice or libreoffice?

Comment: Managed to process the file on excel for windows. Too bad there's no easy way to do this on a Mac :(

Comment: Could be a feature to bring to Microsoft's attention for future versions.